# Cannot convert string to DateTime within a LINQ expression

Tags: c#, datetime, linq-to-xml

I am using a LINQ to XML expression to deserialize some XML data into a list of objects. My object is simply a collection fields:

```
public class DataObject
{
 private string Name { get; set; }
 private DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the LINQ query:

```
XDocument linqXml = XDocument.Parse(dataToDeserialize.OuterXml)
List<DataObject> MyObjects = (from object in linqXml.Descendants("object")
select new DataObject
{
 Name = object.Element("Name").Value,
 Date = Convert.ToDateTime(object.Element("Date").Value)
}
```

When I run this, the LINQ query throws a FormatException: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

The date string in the XML is formatted in UTC: 2013-05-02T11:25:35-06:00

To test I tried a conversion of the date time and it correctly returns the DateTime object.

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2013-05-02T11:25:35-06:00");
```

And the string properly converts to a new DateTime object. If I switch the date field on my object to a string type, and then convert it in another method, it converts. It just seems not to work when part of the LINQ query.

I'm stumped on this one. I've tried using DateTime.Parse(string) as well, but that throws the same exception. Is there any way to do this conversion within the query or do I have to convert the fields after the objects have been created?

Edited to add:

Sample XML:
The attributes in each tag are generated by the transaction engine I'm querying to get this data. I pulled the text of the XML while debugging and there appears to be no additional whitespace between the Date tags.

```
<Object>
 <Name __genericType="String" __specificType="[String]" __nodeType="DataField">HelloThere</Name>
 <Date __genericType="Timestamp" __specificType="[TimeStamp]" __nodeType="DataField">2013-05-12T11:08:04-06:00</Date>
</Object>
```

Comment: can you show your xml? also your linq query won't compile as there is a missing parenthesis

Comment: you close that parenthesis at Date = Convert.ToDateTime(object.Element("Date").Value in the actual code right

Comment: Maybe you have some extra white space in the XML... have you tried `Convert.ToDateTime(string.Trim(object.Element("Date").Value))`? Does your `Date` element only contain the date or it has some other child elements?

Comment: @Jonesy Yes, that's closed in my real code. Thanks. Let me get some sample of the XML and I will edit it in.

Comment: @nemesv The `Date` element only contains the UTC string, it has no children.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you change `DataObject.Date` to a string, then use `Date = object.Element("Date").Value`, and finaly `Convert.ToDateTime(MyObjects[0].Date)` it works fine?

Comment: @Cemafor Yes that's right.

Comment: @mallan1121 In that case, I'm with you. That is just weird.

Comment: It is weird. Your code with your sample XML in a newly created console app is working just fine ... so there is something else causing the problem what you haven't show us...

Comment: Well, I feel sheepish. Dug a little deeper and it's being caused by a different object node in my XML file having nothing in between it's Date tags. . .. So of course, you can't convert an empty string to a datetime.

Comment: I'm not quite sure on the etiquette here, if I realize my own dumb mistake, should I close the question?

Comment: @mallan1121 until you don't have an upvoted answer you can simple delete your question.

Comment: "The date string in the XML is formatted in UTC" - no, it's formatted as ISO8601.  It is clearly 6 hours behind UTC.  UTC is not a format - it's the zero offset.  And if you have an offset, your property should be declared as `DateTimeOffset` instead of `DateTime`.